# Is it possible to simplify value creation/usage in MPFR?

Tags: c++, gmp, mpfr

Suppose that I want to use [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org) to compute pi; I have the following code, which works:

```
mpfr_t PI;
mpfr_t one;
mpfr_init(PI);
mpfr_init(one);
mpfr_set_d(one, 1, MPFR_RNDN);
mpfr_asin(PI, one, MPFR_RNDN);
mpfr_mul_d(PI, PI, 2, MPFR_RNDN);
```

This is equivalent to "pi = 2 * arcsin(1)". I recognize that MPFR is never going to exactly roll off the keyboard, but I'm new to this library, and I would like to know if there's a way to avoid defining the variable "one"; i.e., I would like the code to look like this:

```
mpfr_t PI;
mpfr_init(PI);
mpfr_asin(PI, <the number 1>, MPFR_RNDN);
mpfr_mul_d(PI, PI, 2, MPFR_RNDN);
```

I can easily write something myself that takes a double and returns an mpfr_t object, to put in place of the <...>. My real question is: **is this already built into MPFR somewhere?**

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that building a function myself to return an mpfr_t object is not a good solution, because it results in a memory leak. The variable would have to be initialized inside of the utility function, and then there would be no way to clear it. The only solution I know of is to write wrappers for all of the special functions, such as arcsin and log. I would like a cleaner solution, preferably using something built into MPFR.

Comment: I think there is a class library that comes with MPFR, it should do conversion for you.

Comment: @brian beuning Could you elaborate? I didn't see anything in the documentation.

Comment: I think this is what @brian was referring to: http://math.berkeley.edu/~wilken/code/gmpfrxx/

Comment: If all you want is pi, there is mpfr_const_pi. Also, the macro MPFR_DECL_INIT can be used to have 2 lines fewer (you didn't show mpfr_clear), and is a bit cheaper. Otherwise, the homepage mentions 2 or 3 C++ wrappers. Boost.Multiprecision may also have one.